# Where is the error in my Python script?

Tags: file, ftp, passwords, urllib2

I scripted download script.
When it runs it throws an error.

Code:

```
import urllib2, shutil

ftpfile = urllib2.urlopen("ftp://user:password@domain.com/file.txt")

localfile = open("C:\\dtmp", "wb")
shutil.copyfileobj(ftpfile, localfile)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "download.py", line 4, in <module>

localfile = open("C:\\dtmp", "wb")

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\dtmp'
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have write access on the path you tried to open.

In general it's not a good style to write directly on C:\. Instead you can write in your user directory or in a temporary directory.

```
import os.path
homedir = os.path.expanduser('~')
with open(os.path.join(homedir, 'filename')) as localfile:
  shutil.copyfileobj(ftpfile, localfile)
```

Comment: You can test your access with:
os.access(filename, os.W_OK)

Additionally you can create a temporary directory which has always write access for your user:
http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#module-tempfile